# Pandas: calculate average

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv dataset where I want to calculate the average for all rows The average is calculated from data start at column 14. This is what I have done so far but I am still not getting the average value. Can someone help me with this?

I am also getting confused with this Axis thing.

```
file = ('dataset.csv')

df = pd.read_csv(file)


d_col = df[df.columns[14:]]

mean_value = d_col['mean'] = d_col.mean(axis=1, skipna=True, numeric_only=True)

print mean_value

d_col.to_csv('out.csv')
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a very strange indexing syntax you're using. A clearer way should be:

```
d_col = df.iloc[:, 14:]
```

axis = 0 means taking the average by column, and axis = 1 by the row, which you seem to be doing correctly. I'm not sure what exactly you mean by not getting the average. The d_col should contain your original data and a new column named "mean" containing the result.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't provide sample data see the following sample code. The first column is some text column that should be ignored, whereas the other columns in the DataFrame `df` are the ones that should be used to calculate the mean value.

```
# prepare some dataset
letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'
rows = 10
col1 = np.array(list(letters))[np.random.permutation(len(letters))[:rows]]
df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(col1), pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(rows, 10))], axis=1)

result = df.iloc[:, 1:].mean(axis=1)
```

The result then looks like this:

```
0    0.693024
1   -0.356701
2    0.082385
3   -0.115622
4   -0.060414
5    0.104119
6   -0.435787
7    0.023327
8   -0.144272
9    0.363254
dtype: float64
```

/edit: Change answer above to use `df.iloc` instead of `df[df.columns[...]` as the latter makes problem in case two columns have the same name. Please mark peidaqi's answer as the correct one.

Answer (score 0):

The issue lied here , I was saving d_col as the output csv file instead of  mean_value . It's silly but  i guess that's how you learn to pickup things. Thanks @peidaqi  and others for your explanation.